# powershell script to add users to group if not a member of another group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have an issue with the following script:

```bsh
get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "dc=domain,dc=global" -ResultSetSize $null | where-object {((get-aduser $_.samaccountname -properties memberof).memberof -ne "Mimecast Remote Access Exceptions")} | ForEach {add-adgroupmember -identity "Mimecast Internal Access" -member $_.samaccountname}
```

It is still adding all users but not filtering out users who are members of the remote access exceptions group. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to perform `Get-ADUser` twice.
Then, the `MemberOf` user property is a **collection**, not a single string, so you need to use `-notcontains` instead of `-ne`

Try:

```
# get the DistinguishedName property of the group
$groupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Identity "Mimecast Remote Access Exceptions").DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=domain,dc=global" -Properties MemberOf | 
Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -notcontains $groupDN} | 
ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Mimecast Internal Access" -Members $_ }
```

Comment: Hi theo,thanks for your answer works perfectly and can see where I was going wrong now. Thanks to everyone else who contributed too

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@Theo's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62933996/4749264)

`.memberOf` will return distinguished name strings.  `-notcontains` won't work unless you change the left hand side to the DN.  That might look something like:

```
$DN = 'CN=Mimecast Remote Access Exceptions,OU=SomeOU,DC=domain,DC=global'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=domain,dc=global" -Properties MemberOf | 
Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -notcontains $DN } | 
ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $DN -Members $_ }
```

Obviously correct `$DN` for your environment etc...